# WYSIWYG editor pastes html tags in output textfield

Tags: django, wysiwyg, django-wysiwyg

I use this redactor for admin site [django-wysiwyg-redactor](https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor)

But when I enter some text, it pastes it with html tags. When discovering my source code, I noticed that  html code that is responsible for my input data, is placed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use "safe", the built-in template filter to render the html properly in your template. Example:

{{ myTextField|safe }}

[Safe in django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)